# How to use SSIS and HTTPS to access a secure website: Screen Scraping

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis, connection, screen-scraping

I've been online trying to find examples of how to screen scrape and or download a file from an authenticated website using SSIS. However, I been unsucessful in doing so. Can someone please provide direction with how to tackle this situation.

Tools:

SSIS - Programming Language C#

Thank you

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend this book by Donald Farmer: [The Rational Guide to Extending SSIS 2005 with Script](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932577254) .The examples are in VB rather than C# but the programming concepts are there. Use a VB to C# converter if needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will see if I can get the book later today.

Comment: Please consider marking this as the correct answer if it pointed you in the right direction.